# 401 HTTP Response, when I load client secret and client-ID from praw.ini

Tags: python, http, reddit, http-status-code-401, praw

Recently, I started a PRAW project aiming to scrape from the r/todayilearned subreddit. Browsing through the docs, if found that the best way to load up the client-id, client secret, username, and password was to store it in the praw.ini file.

This is the format I used where the ".........." were filled by the respective inputs.

```
[TIL]
client_id="´............"
client_secret="............"
password="............"
username=".........."
user_agent="TIL by u/........"
```

I executed this code and I get

```
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit("TIL")
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('learnpython')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\python\TIL\src\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    for submission in subreddit.get_hot():
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\praw\models\reddit\base.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    self._fetch()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\praw\models\reddit\subreddit.py", line 584, in _fetch
    data = self._fetch_data()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\praw\models\reddit\subreddit.py", line 581, in _fetch_data
    return self._reddit.request("GET", path, params)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 849, in request
    return self._core.request(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 328, in request
    return self._request_with_retries(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 226, in _request_with_retries
    response, saved_exception = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 183, in _make_request 
    response = self._rate_limiter.call(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\rate_limit.py", line 33, in call
    kwargs["headers"] = set_header_callback()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 281, in _set_header_callback
    self._authorizer.refresh()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 379, in refresh
    self._request_token(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 155, in _request_token    
    response = self._authenticator._post(url, **data)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 38, in _post
    raise ResponseException(response)
prawcore.exceptions.ResponseException: received 401 HTTP response
```

But, when I do this, It works.

```
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(
client_id="´............",
client_secret="............",
password="............",
username="..........",
user_agent="TIL by u/........"
)

subreddit = reddit.subreddit('learnpython')
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you try to use `subreddit` to get any data? i.e. `for item in subreddit.comments():   print(item)`. Maybe it will raise error in both versions

Comment: Yes, I did use the subreddit, I didn't include it here. Anyway, I have given up on trying to get praw.ini to work, and I have switched to store these values in a .env file. Still, thanks a lot for answering my question!

Comment: This is a totally unrelated question, but I want to gather the data from the subreddits and then periodically display it. Should I store it in a database? and if so, should I purge the database after the program is closed?

Comment: why to keep it in database if you want to purge it. Simpler is to keep it in memory.

Comment: I didn't even try to answer question - I would have to find my `client ID` to test code and see how it works with `.ini`. Maybe problem is some mistake in file or different encoding. You would have to display these values or compare them with strings which you have directly in code.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and it has to be without `" "`

```
[TIL]
client_id=2Ca......Mh4
client_secret=Bq7............X0z
password=SeCrEtPaSsWoRd
username=james_bond
user_agent=TIL by u/james_bond
```

but it can use spaces to make it more readable

```
[TIL]
client_id = 2Ca......Mh4
client_secret = Bq7............X0z
password = SeCrEtPaSsWoRd
username = james_bond
user_agent = TIL by u/james_bond
```

---

**BTW:**

It may also use `:` instead of `=`

```
[TIL]
client_id:2Ca......Mh4
client_secret:Bq7............X0z
password:SeCrEtPaSsWoRd
username:james_bond
user_agent:TIL by u/james_bond
```

```
[TIL]
client_id : 2Ca......Mh4
client_secret : Bq7............X0z
password : SeCrEtPaSsWoRd
username : james_bond
user_agent : TIL by u/james_bond
```

---

**EDIT:**

I checked documentation [praw.ini Files](https://asyncpraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/configuration/prawini.html) and it shows examples also without `" "`

Comment: Thanks! I can finally start on my project.

Comment: you can mark my answer as accepted and few minutes later you can upvote it.